# Cast/Convert char type into int based on what they char type says

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am querying demographics where I need to categorize races as one of five: American Indian, Asian, Black, White, Pacific ISL.  I need to create a column where if they are more than one race it outputs 'M' and if not it will output the appropriate code for that race.  Each race is coded 'Y' or NULL in original table.

```
IIf((SD.[RACE_AMER_INDIAN]+SD.[RACE_ASIAN]+SD.[RACE_BLACK]+SD.[RACE_PACIFIC_ISL]+SD.[RACE_WHITE])>1,'M',
IIf(SD.[RACE_AMER_INDIAN]='Y','I',
IIf(SD.[RACE_ASIAN]='Y','A',
IIf(SD.[RACE_BLACK]='Y','B',
IIf(SD.[RACE_PACIFIC_ISL]='Y','P',
IIf(SD.[RACE_WHITE]='Y','W','')))))) AS Race
```

I am sure there are many ways to do this, I was trying to use Convert/Cast on these to make numeric, but was having difficulty.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding up the number of `Y`s can be tricky.  Here is one method:

```
(case when len(concat(SD.[RACE_AMER_INDIAN], SD.[RACE_ASIAN], SD.[RACE_BLACK], SD.[RACE_PACIFIC_ISL], SD.[RACE_WHITE]) > 1
      then 'M'
      when SD.[RACE_AMER_INDIAN] = 'Y' then 'I'
      when SD.[RACE_ASIAN] = 'Y' then 'A'
      when SD.[RACE_BLACK] = 'Y' then 'B'
      when SD.[RACE_PACIFIC_ISL] = 'Y' then 'P'
      when SD.[RACE_WHITE] = 'Y' then 'W'
      else ''
 end) as Race
```

Comment: Commas between `when` clauses?

Answer (score 0):

If you use [`Concat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in your first test it will handle `NULL` values by converting them to empty strings. If the result has a length greater than `1` then you have your `'M'` condition. Using a [searched `case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) rather than nested `IIF`s will make life easier:

```
case
  when Len( Concat( SD.[RACE_AMER_INDIAN], SD.[RACE_ASIAN], SD.[RACE_BLACK], SD.[RACE_PACIFIC_ISL], SD.[RACE_WHITE] ) ) > 1 then 'M'
  when SD.[RACE_AMER_INDIAN] = 'Y' then 'I'
  when SD.[RACE_ASIAN] = 'Y' then 'A'
  when SD.[RACE_BLACK] = 'Y' then 'B'
  when SD.[RACE_PACIFIC_ISL] = 'Y' then 'P'
  when SD.[RACE_WHITE] = 'Y' then 'W'
  else '?' end as Race
```